# JavaScript script not running?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting

The idea of this code is to show an unordered list of HTML elements, but for some reason, it seems like it doesn't work.

I'm using Sublime Text to write the script and the HTML code. I've tried to execute the script through Chrome developers console, and it didn't work either.

```
// 1) Crear una lista desordenada con 10 elementos dentro usando un bucle for.
//    Tener en cuenta que solo se le puede hacer un único appendChild al ul creado, 
//    asi minimizamos el tiempo de modificaciones en el DOM.

var list = document.createElement('ul');
var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  let element = document.createElement('li');
  element.innerText = "Elemento " + i;
  elements.appendChild(element);
}

list.appendChild(elements);
document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've written, it should work fine. There's no way for us to tell why it isn't working for you.

Comment: We're gonna need more code. Perhaps provide your HTML so we can see whether the script tag is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when you do the same thing via a function after DOM is loaded. It gives this error in the console (F12 in Chrome) otherwise -

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null`

This is perhaps because of the unavailability of DOM during initial execution of the script and the hence the node is not available for the 'appendChild' function call.

Check this out, I am calling the same code via a function which works as expected -

```
<html>
<script> 
    //var list = document.getElementById('test');
    //var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();
    console.log(list);
    for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++){
       /* let element = document.createElement('li');

        element.innerText = "Elemento " + i;
        console.log(i);*/

        var node = document.createElement("LI");                 // Create a <li> node
        var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");         // Create a text node
        node.appendChild(textnode);                              // Append the text to <li>
        document.getElementById('myList').appendChild(node);
    }

    //list.appendChild(elements);

    //document.appendChild(list);
     function myFunction() {
            var node = document.createElement("LI");
            var textnode = document.createTextNode("Water");
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
        }

</script>
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <ul id="myList">
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your script tag is in the correct place.

> JavaScript in `<head>` or `<body>` You can place any number of scripts in an HTML document. Scripts can be placed in the `<body>`, or in the `<head>` section of an HTML page, or in both.

```
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Your Page</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           // javascript goes here
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Your body goes here.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
var list = document.createElement('ul');
var elements = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) {
    let element = document.createElement('li');
    element.innerText = "Elemento " + i;
    elements.appendChild(element);
}

list.appendChild(elements);
document.body.appendChild(list);
```

It's working fine on our end.

Comment: `text/javascript` is the default, you don't have to specify it.

Comment: I created a variable: "var body = document.querySelector("body");" and then I replaced "document.body.appendChild(list);" with "body.appendChild(list);" to make it work in google chrome. I guess that my problem was located on "document.body.appendChild(list);"?